# Why is this not an acceptable spawn location?

Tags: terraria

I can't wrap my head around it. Right clicking this bed doesn't give the "Spawn point set" message.

[image: Spawn location]

Comment: @Raven You could be right, but I didn't find any quotes in both Terraria wikis.

Comment: No, I have a home deeper than this with a set spawnpoint

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As far as I know, you need to have a door for a house to register as a house, and no "open" spaces or gaps in the outer walls. If you look to the left of the building you're in, you have a small gap on the floor where you have the bed. Try to cover it and, theoretically, it should work.

Comment: Good catch, I didn't see the hole in the wall at a first sight. Probably will solve.

Comment: Much obliged. Didn't notice that hole